# Vaadin File Uploading using FileFilter

Tags: vaadin

I am Using Vaadin Framework. I need to Upload Files in the format of PDF,JAR & ZIP only. I tried with this code.This code is also I got from STACK OVER FLOW.

```
public void uploadStarted(StartedEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("***Upload: uploadStarted()");

                ArrayList<String> allowedMimeTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
                allowedMimeTypes.add("application/java-archive");
                allowedMimeTypes.add("application/pdf");
                allowedMimeTypes.add("application/zip");
                String contentType = event.getMIMEType();
                boolean allowed = false;
                System.out.println(":::::::::::::contentType::::::"
                        + contentType);
                for (int i = 0; i < allowedMimeTypes.size(); i++) {

                    if (contentType.equalsIgnoreCase(allowedMimeTypes.get(i))) {

                        allowed = true;
                        break;
                    }

                }
                try {
                    if (allowed) {
                        System.out.println("boolean value:::::::allowed"
                                + allowed);
                        finalDeedUpload.setReceiver(finalDeedFileUploadHandler);
                        finalDeedUpload.addListener(finalDeedFileUploadHandler);

                    } else {

                        showWarningNotification(
                                "Error:Please Upload File in Given Format", "");

                    }
```

This is working for while uploading PDf files it's working, while uploading Zip OR Jar file and any other file it is showing NULLPOINTER EXCEPTION.
Please help me.

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of the exception

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. As it is, it is unclear what your problem and question are. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin has a special upload component which is easy to use. There is a whole chapter in Book of Vaadin related to this component.

https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.upload.html

Comment: It Doesn't help me. I need to filter the files.

Comment: Can you debug your code and say on which line there is NPE?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.vaadin.ui.Upload$1.getOutputStream(Upload.java:1007)
 at com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractCommunicationManager.streamToReceiver(AbstractCommunicationManager.java:562)
 ... 22 more

Comment: @mchinta did you get any solution , i am getting similar exception while uploading a file and in my case , its any file whether its .png or .pdf.

Answer (score 0):

In Vaadin 14 there is a method `setAcceptedFileTypes` at class `Upload`:

```
MemoryBuffer buffer = new MemoryBuffer();
Upload upload = new Upload(buffer);
upload.setAcceptedFileTypes(new String[]{"application/zip", "application/pdf", "application/java-archive"});
```

The method `setAcceptedFileTypes` sets the HTML attribute `accept` at the `<input type="file">` element and therefore limits / filters what the application user can upload.